# Cannot use service that is provided in 'root' (from external library) in app.component.ts

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, micro-frontend, angular16

I am working on Micro frontend (Module federation). I have three projects, let's say `shell`, `mfe`, `ui-ux-lib`.

In `ui-ux-lib`, I created `loading.service.ts` (provided in `root`), I export this service at `public-api.ts`

**loading.service.ts**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class LoadingService {
  private _loadingComponentRef: Nullable<ComponentRef<LoadingComponent>> = null;
  private _rootViewContainerRef!: ViewContainerRef;

  // The rest
}
```

In `shell` app, I use `LoadingService` from `ui-ux-lib`, they are **totally fine** if I use in components except `AppComponent`. When I try to inject `LoadingService` in `AppComponent`, I got this error: **TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'injector')**

[image]

are there any things wrong from my configuration?

I tried to put `LoadingService` in `AppModule` providers but it doesn't work